# Nearest neighbor/Travelling salesman problem in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman

I want to solve nearest neighbors/travelling salesman problem using Neo4j database. I have 200 cities that are connect with one another. I have tried using this code below to solve the problem but it takes forever to calculate.

```
MATCH (from:Node {name: "Source node" })
MATCH path = (from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*6]->()
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) WHERE 1 = length(filter(m in nodes(path) WHERE m = n)))
AND length(nodes(path)) = 7
RETURN path,
    reduce(distance = 0, edge in relationships(path) | distance + edge.distance)
    AS totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at: https://towardsdatascience.com/part-2-exploring-pathfinding-graph-algorithms-e194ffb7f569

Comment: @TomažBratanič do You know any source when I can find nearest neighbors algorithm for travelling salesman problem? Because given source is based on shortest paths

Comment: there is no out of the box algorithm in neo4j